# Does Rocket League on Switch have control issues?

Tags: rocket-league, nintendo-switch

I play Rocket League at home from both my desktop and the Switch. Both use a wired connection to a wifi extender to connect to the internet, but control on the PC version is noticeably more responsive. Playing on the Switch feels like I'm driving in water. Is this a known Switch issue? Do I have some controller sync issues?

Comment: What are you using for controllers on the PC and the switch?

Comment: Yep. I play on PC, Switch, and PS4. I get the same issue with Switch as I do on PS4. I should try playing it on my PC monitors some time...

Comment: I use a Steam controller on the PC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the same feeling when playing Rocket League on PS4.  It's because the input latency *(time for your button presses to be reflected on screen)* is generally much higher on console.  This is because:

- **TVs** generally have much higher latency than monitors, especially ones that have fancy effects like motion interpolation or noise reduction.  Many TVs have a "gaming mode" that disables those effects and decreases latency - **make sure Gaming Mode is on!**  However, even then, their latency still tends to be much higher than monitors.

  You can check your TV's input latency [here](https://displaylag.com/display-database/).  My TV is on the better end of things, and it still has 34ms = 2 frames of latency in gaming mode!
- Consoles usually use **wireless controllers** whereas many gamers use wired on their PCs.  This generally adds an extra frame or two of latency. There's nothing you can do about that on Switch, but on PS4 the newer DS4s support wired-mode.  I'm not sure about XBox.
- **Lower framerates** will increase latency compared to PC by increasing the time between frames.  Rocket League on Switch runs at 60fps, so that shouldn't be an issue unless you're used to >60fps on PC.

Comment: I have game mode enabled on my TV, but I dont really know what the latency is so that could be it. Thanks, I guess I'll stick to my desktop for now, although it is awesome to be able to take Rocket League with home for the weekend :D

Comment: Actually, you can use wired mode on Switch as well, but only if you own the Pro controller. It's an option that has been added in some update.